# Cornacchia's Algorithm

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, class-field-theory

Can any one give  the representation for  a prime number 9444732965601851473921 as $x^2+15y^2$. I tried cubic cornacchia algorithm in nzmath implemented through python, but in vain. I also tried through tonelli-shanks algorithm, coded in python  but gives message memory full. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sushma, this problem is similar to $x^2 - 2 y^2 = p,$ with the important change that reduction of positive definite forms is much, much easier than indefinite. Note that $x^2 + 23 y^2 = p$ is impossible, no square root of $(-92).$ Also note that the principal genus in discriminant $(-140)$ has three classes, $$ x^2 + 35 y^2, \; 4 x^2 + 2 xy + 9 y^2, \; 4 x^2 - 2 xy + 9 y^2. $$ So we do not know yet whether your prime is represented by $x^2 + 35 y^2.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
?  p  =  9444732965601851473921
%1 = 9444732965601851473921
? isprime(p)
%2 = 1
? 
factormod( x^2 + 60, p)

%3 = 
[Mod(1, 9444732965601851473921)*x + Mod(3629625893082944101553, 9444732965601851473921) 1]

[Mod(1, 9444732965601851473921)*x + Mod(5815107072518907372368, 9444732965601851473921) 1]

? 


? 
? factormod( x^2 + 92, p)
%4 = 
[Mod(1, 9444732965601851473921)*x^2 + Mod(92, 9444732965601851473921) 1]

? 
? 
? 
? 
? factormod( x^2 + 140, p)
%5 = 
[Mod(1, 9444732965601851473921)*x + Mod(2574641518713546507379, 9444732965601851473921) 1]

[Mod(1, 9444732965601851473921)*x + Mod(6870091446888304966542, 9444732965601851473921) 1]


?  ( 6870091446888304966542^2 + 140) % p
%10 = 0
? 
? q = ( 6870091446888304966542^2 + 140) / ( 4 * p) 
%12 = 1249324799878029471956
? 

POSITIVE FORM TO BE GAUSS REDUCED:
< 9444732965601851473921 , 6870091446888304966542 , 1249324799878029471956 >
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Answer (score 9):

$$9444732965601851473921 = 97169949911^2 + 15\times 426911380^2$$

Found using (simple-minded) pari/gp script on my laptop in 16 minutes 51 seconds.

The script I used was:

```
N=9444732965601851473921;
for (a=1,1000000000,k=N-15*a*a;if (k==floor(sqrt(k))^2,print(a)))
```

Not an elegant script, but something like this is usually my first try just to see if there are any small-ish solutions in cases like this.

**Edit**

I have discovered that pari/gp actually does the whole thing for you, and extremely quickly, with just two commands:

```
? x=Qfb(1,0,15)
? qfbsolve(x,9444732965601851473921)
```

This gives the representation as

```
 = [97169949911, 426911380]
```

(with no noticeable delay)

If there is no solution (as in the other 2 cases you mentioned in a comment) then the command just gives the response 0.

Comment: thank you really, did you write any program or used some command, please help, I wanted to find for some numbers like, 21,35 etc

Comment: Pari/gp is worth looking into for number theory work: it is easy to program, it is free, and is is designed specifically for number theory calculations.

Comment: [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) has `TwoSquares` function: `TwoSquares(9444732965601851473921)` instantly returns `[68719476735,68719476736]`. Maybe you can look at its code and borrow some ideas.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov, this is true, as the given prime is $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, but I want a representation of type $x^2+ny^2$, is there any command in GAP, for that

Comment: @OldJohn, if you don't mind, can you get a rep, for the same prime as $x^2+35y^2$, and $x^2+23y^2$ my laptop hangs, if I do it; I got it for n=21,

Comment: @sushma I will have a go - maybe we should continue this in the chatroom?

Comment: yes sure, but how

Comment: @sushma There is a link to "chat" at the top of the page - or try [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)

Comment: @Sushma: yes, I've noticed this. There is no built-in command in GAP for that. The [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) avenue seems promising, I suggest to go along it further.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov, as long as one is sticking with $x^2 + n y^2 = p,$ for positive $n,$ one may use the Hardy-Muskat-Williams algorithm. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96762/sum-of-squares-diophantine-equation Meanwhile, for prime target, one needs only one "seed" value.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for the interesting link!

Comment: @OldJohn, Thank you very much for your answer. I did not open this for two days, thank you

Comment: @sushma No problem - you are very welcome.

Comment: @OldJohn, Hi, really nice of you to give the commands in Pari/GP, it is working fine I could check for larger primes and without any time delay, it does give the answer, THANKS!!

Comment: @OldJohn, what is your name I would like to acknowledge you in a small paper that I am writing please reply

Comment: @Sushma You can find me [here on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/users/24963/john-wordsworth)

Answer (score 4):

Alright, $x^2 + 35 y^2 = p$ does not work either. In this case it is a highly nontrivial fact, but the proof is just that a different form  of the same discriminant, $4 x^2 + 2 x y + 9 y^2,$ does represent it, as well as its "opposite" $4 x^2 - 2 x y + 9 y^2$ of course:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
? 
? x = 13234853864
%7 = 13234853864
? 
? y = -32675150643
%8 = -32675150643
? 
? 4 * x^2 + 2 * x * y + 9 * y^2   
%9 = 9444732965601851473921
?
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
Fri Nov 22 22:46:17 PST 2013

< 9444732965601851473921, 6870091446888304966542, 1249324799878029471956> 
< 1249324799878029471956, -6870091446888304966542, 9444732965601851473921> 
 t = 3
< 1249324799878029471956, 625857352379871865194, 78381823839201821899> 
< 78381823839201821899, -625857352379871865194, 1249324799878029471956> 
 t = 4
< 78381823839201821899, 1197238333742709998, 4571785771161564> 
< 4571785771161564, -1197238333742709998, 78381823839201821899> 
 t = 131
< 4571785771161564, 569538301619770, 17737810411965> 
< 17737810411965, -569538301619770, 4571785771161564> 
 t = 16
< 17737810411965, -1928368436890, 52410708284> 
< 52410708284, 1928368436890, 17737810411965> 
 t = -18
< 52410708284, 41582938666, 8248031961> 
< 8248031961, -41582938666, 52410708284> 
 t = 3
< 8248031961, 7905253100, 1894179935> 
< 1894179935, -7905253100, 8248031961> 
 t = 2
< 1894179935, -328533360, 14245501> 
< 14245501, 328533360, 1894179935> 
 t = -12
< 14245501, -13358664, 3131759> 
< 3131759, 13358664, 14245501> 
 t = -2
< 3131759, 831628, 55209> 
< 55209, -831628, 3131759> 
 t = 8
< 55209, 51716, 12111> 
< 12111, -51716, 55209> 
 t = 2
< 12111, -3272, 221> 
< 221, 3272, 12111> 
 t = -7
< 221, 178, 36> 
< 36, -178, 221> 
 t = 2
< 36, -34, 9> 
< 9, 34, 36> 
 t = -2
< 9, -2, 4> 
< 4, 2, 9> 
reduction matrix
11883939640     4813511227
-32675150643     -13234853864

inverse matrix
-13234853864     -4813511227
32675150643     11883939640

Fri Nov 22 22:46:17 PST 2013
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Old John called my attention to a pair [of commands in gp-pari](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/doc.html) that solve this type of problem instantaneously, as long as the target value is prime. Pari is free software, I do not see any reason it should be difficult to install on a laptop. Anyway, samples, including both positive and indefinite forms. Note that the expression given for $4x^2 - 2 x y + 9 y^2 = p$ can just be multiplied by $4$ and the square completed to solve $u^2 + 35 v^2 = 4p.$

```
? x = Qfb(4,-2,9)
%1 = Qfb(4, -2, 9)
? 
? qfbsolve(x,9444732965601851473921) 
%2 = [-13234853864, -32675150643]
? 
? 

? x = Qfb(1,0,35)
%3 = Qfb(1, 0, 35)
? qfbsolve(x,9444732965601851473921) 
%4 = 0
? 
? 


? x = Qfb(1,0,-2)
%5 = Qfb(1, 0, -2, 0.E-28)
? 
?  qfbsolve(x,17) 
%6 = [-5, -2]
? 
? qfbsolve(x,9444732965601851473921)
%7 = [-146996209027, -77984461602]
?
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Will jagy It is really a wonderful reply from your side for my doubt. Kindly excuse me for not replying, as I did not open this site for two days, also a small doubt:  how did you get two different answers for the same prime qfbsolve(x,9444732965601851473921) 
%2 = [-13234853864, -32675150643] and qfbsolve(x,9444732965601851473921)
%7 = [-146996209027, -77984461602]

Comment: @Sushma, the first is for the form $4x^2 - 2 xy + 9 y^2.$ The second is for the form $x^2 - 2 y^2.$

Comment: Will Jagy, thank you very much, for clearing the doubt.

Comment: Will Jagy, really kind of you to work out the problem and spend the time on this, it really helped me to check for more prime numbers of that nature. THANKS!!